# MySQL select values from one table based on array of ids from another table

Tags: javascript, mysql, sql, node.js

I found many PHP examples which use `map` and `implode` to structure their string...I'm using Node and Javascript and I think that might be the problem.  I have an array of ids and I'm saving it like this:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4].join();
```

That's being stored and I'm trying to run a query:

```
SELECT sr.id, sr.name, sr.city FROM table1 AS sr 
JOIN table2 AS st WHERE sr.city = st.city AND sr.id IN (st.ids);
```

So both tables have a column city, table2 having multiple records, table1 only has one.  The 'ids' column is of type TEXT in table2.  Problem is it's only returning the row with id 1.  If I do this:

```
SELECT sr.id, sr.name, sr.city FROM table1 AS sr 
JOIN table2 AS st WHERE sr.city = st.city AND sr.id IN (1,2);
```

I will get rows 1 and 2.  What's causing the problem?  I tried `[1, 2, 3, 4].join(', ');` and that didn't help.  Any suggestions?

Comment: y the javascript tag?

Comment: @Iceman because I'm using Node.js and modifying the value using Javascript before saving it

Comment: First suggestion don't store concatenated strings that you will want to join on/use in a query like that it makes things a pain!  Next if you are going to do that anyway look up split string methods so split the string to a table and then do a join rather than in.  If you don't want to do split string you can fake it with some wildcard searches but that has huge potential issues and then you can also go down the dynamic sql path.  All methods suggest Don't store concatenated strings if you will use them for purposes like this.

Comment: You probably want to look at using [Sequelize](http://sequelizejs.com) to do this for you.

Comment: How do you concatenate those strings?

Comment: @HiI'mFrogatto using the JavaScript join method. The entry in the database look like 1,2,3,4.

Comment: @denikov How do you concatenate `st.ids` and the main query string?

Comment: @HiI'mFrogatto not quite sure what you're asking. I'm not concatenating the ids, they come in as an array and I'm using join() to convert them to a string, then updating the column value.

Comment: @denikov Where/How do you run the query?

Comment: @HiI'mFrogatto I'm running it just as it is written there using felixge/node-mysql module.

Comment: @denikov Ok. Could you please share your code with us?

Comment: `"SELECT sr.id, sr.name, sr.city FROM table1 AS sr 
JOIN table2 AS st WHERE sr.city = st.city AND sr.id IN (" + ids.join(",")+ ")"`

Comment: @AikonMogwai The problem with your solution is the ids are already joined and inside the database.  I'm running the query as part of an API that I'm creating, so when a client requests for this information I need to run the query as I stated in the question.  So I need to use `st.ids` inside the query

Comment: `SELECT sr.id, sr.name, sr.city FROM table1 AS sr JOIN table2 AS st WHERE sr.city = st.city AND INSTR(st.ids, sr.id) != 0`

Answer (score 0):

I'm using MySQL v5.7 so I have access to JSON functions...I should've used this in the first place.  The solution which works as I wanted is:

```
SELECT sr.id, sr.name, sr.city FROM table1 AS sr 
JOIN table2 AS st WHERE sr.city = st.city AND 
JSON_SEARCH(st.ids, 'one', sr.id) IS NOT NULL;
```

Love the new JSON support feature...altho it comes with its caveats.  For example, the ids in the array have to be strings, the ids cannot be `int`'s.  `JSON_SEARCH` kept on returning `NULL` for paths to the ids until I converted them to strings.  Trial and error...